# What does origin-based security model mean?

Tags: html, security, browser, websocket

I am studying websocket [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) where the security model of web-socket is stated to be [**origin-based security model**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-9) . As well it is mentioned that this security model is used by web browsers. So what is this *origin-based security model* about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, data/script is classified as trusted or not based on where it's loaded from, if you know about same origin policy or cross origin resource sharing (CORS) then you know that browsers puts some restrictions on Javascript that is loaded from different domains.

Comment: No, CORS does not apply to WebSocket.

Answer (score 3):

CORS does not apply to WebSocket. A page JS can connect to any WebSocket server. It's just that *browser* WebSocket clients will send an `origin` header, which you may or may not use in your server to deny the client. However, non-browser clients can fake that, so it's of limited use.

Answer (score 1):

What happens:

- Client connects to Server, setting up TCP connection with HTTP layered on top.
- In case of HTTPS, there is also an agreement on the cryptographic protocol to use, a key exchange and possibly a certificate exchange. If a certificate exchange happens:

  - Client may ascertain that the Server is what it pretends it is by verifying the certificate of the Server using the public key of the Server (generally done tp make sure there is no man-in-the-middle attack going on or DNS spoofing is happening etc.)
  - Server may ascertain that the Client is what it pretends it is by verifying the certificate of the Client using the public key of the Client (only done in cases where the use case demands that the Client identity is important)
- Connection is established! From here on, anything that goes over the TCP connection is considered *healthy*. "Going over the connection" means "same origin": It comes from the same client (or it comes from the same server).

It might well be that there is an evil hack on the client (or even the server) that borks the existing connection on the TCP or HTTP level and injects its own packets, data, requests or XML blocks. **Too bad!** There is no way this can be precluded in the described approach. One would need to have additional checks on the protocol, e.g. have a separate signature on each individual request signed by mutually trusted hardware modules installed by ${company representative} or something similarly complex.